# How to reverse draw animation for circle?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation

I have created draw circle animation.
When user tap touchdown on button the animation goes to 100% ,  but when user move finger away it pauses.
What i want to do now is to make this animation goes to 0% (start value) instead of pause.

```
var shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
var cabAnim = CABasicAnimation()
var firstAnimation = true

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 100, height: 50))
    button.backgroundColor = .blue
    button.setTitle("123", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(startCircleAnimation), for: .touchDown)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(endCircleAnimation), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)

    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), radius: CGFloat(50), startAngle: -CGFloat(Double.pi/2), endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 3/2), clockwise: true)
    shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
    shapeLayer.position = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.midX, y: self.view.frame.midY)

    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0
    shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0.0

    self.view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}

 @objc func startCircleAnimation() {
    if (firstAnimation) {
        firstAnimation = false
        circleAnimation()
    } else {
        resumeAnimation(layer: shapeLayer)
    }
}
 @objc func endCircleAnimation() {
   pauseAnimation(layer: shapeLayer)
}

func circleAnimation() {
    cabAnim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    cabAnim.duration = 1.5
    cabAnim.repeatCount = 1
    cabAnim.fromValue = 0.0
    cabAnim.toValue = 1.0
    let cam = CAMediaTimingFunctionName.linear
    cabAnim.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: cam)
    shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 1.0
    shapeLayer.add(cabAnim, forKey: "animateCircle")
}


func pauseAnimation(layer: CALayer) {
    let pausedTime: CFTimeInterval = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil)
    layer.speed = 0.0
    layer.timeOffset = pausedTime
}

func resumeAnimation(layer: CALayer) {
    let resAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    let pausedTime: CFTimeInterval = layer.timeOffset
    layer.speed = 1.0
    layer.timeOffset = 0.0
    layer.beginTime = 0.0
    let timeSincePause: CFTimeInterval = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil) - pausedTime
    layer.beginTime = timeSincePause
}
```

How can i make value goes to 0 instead of pause?

Edit:
I want it to move from currentValue to 0 (for example i hold button animation goes to 50% and then i remove finger from button and animation goes to 0%)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this function to create the backward animation, it will draw animation from 100 to 0. i have added the whole project you can take a look.

```
@IBAction func backward(_ sender: Any) {

        let basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        basicAnimation.fromValue = 1
        basicAnimation.toValue = 0
        basicAnimation.duration = 2
        basicAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBackwards
        basicAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

        // Callback function
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
           print("end animation")
        }

        shapeLayer.add(basicAnimation, forKey: "urSoBasic")
    }
```

[image]

**Create ShapeLayer**

```
in most cases, you can call creating shape layer on `ViewDidLoad`

func createShape() {
        // let's start by drawing a circle somehow
        let center = view.center
        let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()

        let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 100, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
        trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath

        trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        trackLayer.lineWidth = 10
        trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        trackLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
        view.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)

        shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
        shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0

        view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
```

**Forward Action**

```
@IBAction func forward(_ sender: Any) {

        let basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")        
        basicAnimation.toValue = 1
        basicAnimation.duration = 2
        basicAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        basicAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        shapeLayer.add(basicAnimation, forKey: "urSoBasic")
    }
```

**Backward Action**

```
@IBAction func backward(_ sender: Any) {

        let basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        basicAnimation.fromValue = 1
        basicAnimation.toValue = 0
        basicAnimation.duration = 2
        basicAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBackwards
        basicAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        // Callback function
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
           print("end animation")
        }
        shapeLayer.add(basicAnimation, forKey: "urSoBasic")
    }
```

On hold or resume logics, you can play with these codes.

Comment: thanks , i can figure it out now. One more question : where i should place code if more circle is 100%?  inside animation function?

Comment: @ShadeToD i couldnt understand your question. can you be more detail ?

Comment: I have 1 button where user can press it and this red circle appears. If the circle is full ( 100% ) i want view to move to the next view controller ( so i want it to performSegue(_:) ). I need to measure when the circle is full. So i am looking for place where i should measure it and how. Maybe u know  that?

Comment: for example ( If (circle == 100%) { performSegue} else {  return }

Comment: @ShadeToD i have updated the question, you can check for the Callback function in the backward action. that block will be called once the animation ends. which means reaches to 100%

Comment: // Callback function
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
           print("end animation")
        } . Ok thanks now i understand everything. Thanks to @karthik